# Custom swift class properties passed by reference?

Tags: swift, class, properties, pass-by-reference

I have a custom class that I've written an equal/not equal function test for. I'm trying to test if an object I've modified is equal to the original object, but whenever I modify the second object, the original object seems to be modified as well. Here's some sample code (you can run this in a Playground):

```
// Custom class
class MyClass {
    var foo: Bool = false

    static func ==(a: MyClass, b: MyClass) -> Bool {
       return (a.foo == b.foo)
    }
    static func !=(a: MyClass, b: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return !(a==b)
    }

    required init() {
        // do nothing
    }
}

let originalObj: MyClass = MyClass()
var tempObj: MyClass = MyClass()

tempObj = originalObj

tempObj.foo = true

print(originalObj.foo) // Output: "true" (?!?!)
print(tempObj == originalObj) // Output: "true" (?!?!)
```

Why does changing the value of `tempObj` change the value of `originalObj`, and how can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: `tempObj = originalObj` makes both reference variables point to the same object in memory. Don't do that if you don't want both to be the same.

Comment: class are reference types. You can use value types like structs and enums. in which case, when you will write, tempObj = originalObj, it will actually copy the object and hence any future changes to originalObj will not modify tempObj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Classes` in swift are `Reference Types` whereas `Structs` are `Value Types`. There are two ways to achieve what you want. You can either use `struct` instead of `class` or write a `copy` method for this class and use that method. Something like this

```
class MyClass {
    var foo: Bool = false

    static func ==(a: MyClass, b: MyClass) -> Bool {
       return (a.foo == b.foo)
    }
    static func !=(a: MyClass, b: MyClass) -> Bool {
        return !(a==b)
    }
    required init() {
        // do nothing
    }
    func copy() -> MyClass {
        let temp = MyClass()
        temp.foo = foo
        return temp
    }
}

let originalObj: MyClass = MyClass()
var tempObj: MyClass = originalObj.copy()
```